# How to show date in top bar of deskop in ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, system-settings

[image]

In the top bar of the  window day and time are shown, but not date. Is it possible to show the date also by changing the setting?

Comment: yes, with gnome-tweaks

Answer (score 20):

I've found 2 ways to do this.

1. from the command line

   ```
   dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/clock-show-date 'true'
   ```

or

2. Install gnome-tweaks and in it there is a setting to show the day/date along with the time in the top bar.  To install, do:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```

After the install, when you run tweaks, you will see on the far left column "Top Bar". Click on that and you'll see the options on the rigth. Turn the one "ON" under clock where it says "Date".

Comment: Can I make the top bar value changes using CLI with tweak?

Comment: Wow, this should really be an option without having to install a tweak tool.

Comment: I've updated my original answer listing two ways of doing this.  One without a tweak and one with.

Comment: Both worked like a charm.  Many thanks for your support.

Comment: Is there anything the tweak tool can't do? :)