# Can I make the top bar value changes using CLI with tweak?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool

I want to show date in top bar using gnome-tweak-tool. I get the GUI solution [How to show date in top bar of deskop in ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040306/how-to-show-date-in-top-bar-of-deskop-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/1040308#1040308)

[image]

I want to get the CLI solution so that I can add this in my post OS installation script.

This question may be helpful to answer this question.
[How can I script the settings made by gnome-tweak-tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971067/how-can-i-script-the-settings-made-by-gnome-tweak-tool)

Answer (score 4):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
```

to enable the option to show date in top bar.

Comment: Thanks. I like your solution. would you tell me from where you get the key `clock-show-date`? That helps me get another key also.

Comment: @alhelal You can install dconf-Editor (GUI application) and browse all the keys and schemas.

Comment: Am I right that `dconf-editor` is a very promising answer to [OP‘s other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971067/how-can-i-script-the-settings-made-by-gnome-tweak-tool)? If so, please write an answer about it there!

Comment: @dessert Hmm... that question has couple of really good answers, but I believe OP (and others) would find this very helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/522833/how-to-dump-all-dconf-gsettings-so-that-i-can-compare-them-between-two-different